# Permission Denied when writing to tmp/data.json

Tags: python, json, windows, flask, permissions

I am running a local flask server and am trying to write to data to a .json file but I get the error message:

**[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'tmp/data.json'**

I am running it on a Windows 10 machine so I cannot use chmod to alter the permissions of the file. I have used:

**icacls data.json /grant Everyone:F**

but I still get the same error message.

The code I am using to write to file is:

```py
with open('tmp/data.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(raw, f)
```

The file will have the data from a user posted form written to it

```py
@app.route('/result/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        # formatting code from the request to a json object then write to file
```

I am running the flask server with the command **flask run** through cmd.exe with administrator privileges

Comment: on which directory are you working on?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal do you mean which directory is the /tmp/data.json in?

Comment: I get this all the time when I have a file open with the same path/name, can be quite annoying but make sure you have it closed. Otherwise try running it as administrator.

Comment: @Bruno I am running it from an admin cmd and I have tried closing all the files when running it but I still get the permission error message